# How to display only one post from post_type on the front page (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a post_type on my site, inside there are many posts, but I only want to display the last 1 post and the previous post is automatically hidden, but not deleted.

For example I have a "News" post_type, there are Sports, Politics, etc.
in the sports section I have 10 posts, but only the last post is displayed on the front page, while others are not visible (only hidden and can still be opened with url)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: If news is post_type then Sports & Politics what is it? Is it category?

Comment: roughly like a category, I want to make it similar to a film site where every episode is made in one post, but only the last one is displayed.

sorry if my question is not clear, I'm very beginner in this matter